# Slow MySQL query with multiple sub-select joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join

This has been bothering me all day:

I have this query which works fine but is quite slow in some cases. The explain result tells me mysql is scanning 40000 rows 3 times. The query joins on approximatily similar sub-selects but there all a little different.

How can I improve this?

```
SET @lastchecktime = (SELECT max(tresults.StartTime) FROM tresults);
SELECT tresults.shopID
 , tshops.OfficialName
 , tresults.Price, tresults.starttime
 , Sub2.minprice
 , Sub2.StartTime
 , Sub3.daystoolow
 , (sub2.minprice/tsupplierproducts.lowestprice) -1 as afwijking
 , If(maxstarttime = @lastchecktime,'yes' ,'no') as notavailable     
FROM
  tresults
INNER JOIN tshops
ON tshops.shopID = tresults.shopID
inner JOIN (SELECT tresults.shopID
                 , max(tresults.StartTime) AS MaxStartTime
            FROM
            tresults
            WHERE
              tresults.pID = 7
              AND tresults.websiteID = 1
              AND tresults.StartTime BETWEEN "2012-08-01" AND "2012-12-01"              
            GROUP BY
              tresults.shopID) Sub1
ON tresults.StartTime = Sub1.MaxStartTime AND Sub1.shopID = tshops.shopID
INNER JOIN (SELECT tresults.shopID
             , tresults.StartTime
             , min(tresults.Price) AS minprice
        FROM
          tresults
        WHERE
          tresults.pID = 7
          AND tresults.websiteID = 1
          AND tresults.StartTime BETWEEN "2012-08-01" AND "2012-12-01"
        GROUP BY
          tresults.shopID) Sub2
ON Sub2.shopID = tshops.shopID
INNER JOIN (SELECT tresults.shopID
             , round(count(tresults.StartTime)/3,0) AS daystoolow
        FROM
          tsupplierproducts
        INNER JOIN tresults
        ON tsupplierproducts.pID = tresults.pID AND tresults.Price < tsupplierproducts.LowestPrice
        WHERE
          tresults.pID = 7
          AND tresults.websiteID = 1
          AND tresults.StartTime BETWEEN "2012-08-01" AND "2012-12-01"
          AND tsupplierproducts.supplierID = 2
        GROUP BY
          tresults.shopID) Sub3
ON Sub3.shopID = tshops.shopID
INNER JOIN tsupplierproducts
ON tsupplierproducts.pID = tresults.pID AND tsupplierproducts.supplierID = 2
WHERE
  tresults.pID = 7
  AND tresults.websiteID = 1
ORDER BY
notavailable desc, tresults.Price DESC
```

The explain result:

```
1, PRIMARY, tsupplierproducts, const, PRIMARY,fk_SupplierID,fk_pID, PRIMARY, 8, const,const, 1, Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, <derived4>, ALL, , , , , 27, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 43, Using where; Using join buffer
1, PRIMARY, <derived3>, ALL, , , , , 43, Using where; Using join buffer
1, PRIMARY, tshops, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Sub1.shopID, 1, Using where
1, PRIMARY, tresults, eq_ref,     PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC,fk_shopID, PRIMARY, 20, Sub1.MaxStartTime,const,Sub3.shopID,const, 1, 
4, DERIVED, tsupplierproducts, const, PRIMARY,fk_SupplierID,fk_pID, PRIMARY, 8, , 1, Using temporary; Using filesort
4, DERIVED, tresults, ref, PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC,     idxPID, 4, , 42048, Using     where
3, DERIVED, tresults, ref, PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC,     idxPID, 4, , 42048,     Using     where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2, DERIVED, tresults, ref, PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC, idxPID, 4, , 42048, Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is first remove the subqueries.

Comment: That doesnt get me anywhere. I need the result of the query above. Removing the subqueries gives me an unwanted result.

Comment: I think what Vijay means, is replace the subqueries with "normal" joins, moving and adapting the GROUP BY bits to the main query. Do you have a simpler example that shows conceptually what you are trying to do?

Comment: You ARE right @davek.. I suggested that to remove sub queries and to replace with joins.

Comment: Normal joins are not adequate. To make it more understandable: I have a result-table with prices of different products from different shops at different times. That results in 3 columns: time, shopid, productID. I want to produce an overview of all shops offering a given product combined with the latest price and the lowest price in the date-range. I think this cant be done without subjoins.